# No audio going into GarageBand

Tags: macos, audio, microphone, garageband

I just got a Blue Snowball iCE, plugged it in and my Mac recognized it fine. In System Preferences > Sound > Input, Blue Snowball shows up and is selected and I see the input level meter moving in response to sound. There are no other mics plugged in.

In Garage Band > Preferences > Audio/MIDI > Input Device set to Blue Snowball and then record and no sound is recorded and the level meter doesn't show any audio input. When I switch to Built In as the source I also get nothing.

I tried plugging the mic into each of the two USB ports with no change.

I also opened the Audio MIDI Setup App and tried turning the volume for the Blue Snowball all the way down and back up which I saw as a recommendation somewhere.

I downloaded Audacity (2.3.0) and it is able to record fine from either the Snowball or the internal mic.

GarageBand 10.3.1

macOS 10.14.1

MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Early 2013)

The Blue mic works fine on a MBP 13" Late 2013 running the same version of macOS and GarageBand.

Comment: Hi, are both Macs on same OSX

Comment: oh, yes... will add

Comment: I went ahead and recorded on the other computer. I no longer have access to the mic so I'm not sure if I can say if this is answered or not with any future answers.

Answer (score 1):

Some solutions found [here:](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2794785)

> Have you set the mic as the input in GarageBand? (make sure the mic is
> plugged in, open GarageBand, click on the GarageBand menu, Chose
> Preferences, Click on the Audio/MIDI from the preferences window tool
> bar. There will be a pulldown menu called "Audio Input," click on that
> menu, and select the Blue Yeti. )
>
> If your still not getting any audio in from the Yeti, have you tried
> setting the Yeti as the audio in in system preferences? if so, do you
> get any activity Level Input bar while it's selected? if not, is input
> volume set to 100%? (far right end of slide)
>
> Have you tried resetting the cable on the mic side?

If none of this works you might have to send it back as deffective.

Comment: Yep both are selected correctly. It can’t be a problem with the mic because it works fine on the second computer.